# System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001 for Test Class

Tags: apex, soql, error, limits

I have come across this error in production but in a test class where I am defining 5 rows only , how come I'm facing this error ?
Also there was no error in QA but error in Dev and Prod.

```
List<Object__c> objList = new List<Object__c>();
    Object__c obj = new Object__c(Delivery_Location__c='Dalian',Ref__c = '13',Volume__c=1, Grad_Volume__c=1,Month__c='January',Year__c='2013',Country__c='ANZ');
    objList.add(obj);
insert objList;
```

Should I remove @isTest(seeAllData=true) ?

Please suggest.

Comment: Btw: even in tests it's not good to query non selective,  it's good to be sure you'll get the records that you want to get. OR validate that you do.

Comment: Besides using seeAllData annotation - are you sure that you insert correct list? In your snippet we can see that you create a new list and then insert another one...

Comment: @neff That was an error in the snippet only . Corrected.

Comment: and can you show/tell us what is done in triggers of Object__c? Looks like there might be something wrong over there because otherwise single element collection insert shouldn't cause such error. It might be a general issue and not test class only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you should remove `seeAllData=true` and never use it again ([Isolation of Test Data in Unit Tests](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_data_access.htm)). Instead create a test data directly in your test class and work only with that data. You have to assume that there is no data you can access in the production org.

[Common Test Utility Classes for Test Data Creation.](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_testing_data_access.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fapex_testing_data_access.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)

In addition your code should respect system limits. Use [Limits Class](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_limits.htm) to access limits dynamically in apex.

Answer (score 2):

The [@isTest(seeAllData=true)](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_seealldata_using.htm) annotation is most likely the cause of this issue. With the annotation the test is seeing all data in your org. Production may have a lot more records in it than other environments which is why you weren't seeing it everywhere.

Your tests should not rely on data that may/may not exist in the org.